# Generate Image of Google map

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I want to allow end users of my website to generate image of google map. How is this possible after the User has selected its location on google map and can then generate the image.

Comment: @Marcelo if you can find a reference to it, you should put that down as an answer.  I was about to do it, but saw you were first to say that

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142821/google-maps-image

Comment: @psubsee2003: I posted a reply. I was hesitant to do it because the question is not a programming question. :)

Answer (score 5):

It's not allowed. See here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_screenshots

> Use of Google Maps imagery in printed materials **and offline media** is
>   subject to the Permission Guidelines published at:
>
> http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html

you can request permission, but I don't think it's easy to obtain, unless you are a paying  business customer.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the "not allowed" part, there might be a way to let your users download the Google Map screen. However this will take some programming. Here is the basic idea:

When the users interact with the Google Map on your page, you can keep track of the used zoom and map boundaries as well as the selected location. With these values, you can use the [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) to let your users download a static image.

Comment: That wouldn't be that much coding to be honest, getting the current viewport and zoom level is just a few lines of code and then building the link to the Static Maps API is quite straightforward.