# Cache google map data

Tags: php, javascript, caching, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a web system that uses a google map to view different data points around my college's campus. I make heavy use of the scrollTo() method from the maps API and I have noticed that when an area goes off-screen and then it is scrolled to again, a new ajax request is made to reload the tile.

Is there a way to cache the area of the campus so that the map can scroll around smoothly??

Answer (score 0):

Caching the area may be against the terms of use. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109369/how-to-cache-google-map-tiles-for-offline-usage) may help you

It has several references to use that may be what you need.

Comment: ...or this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226521/generate-image-of-google-map/12226673#12226673