# rendering complicated images from google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there any way to capture the image from a ***complicated*** Google Maps with some customize overlays like heat gradient. See figures:[image]
Google static map API can only generate static maps(images) with simple polylines or markers, in my situation this is apparently not enough, I want user to capture this kind of images and share it in there twitter fb of g+

see [Google Maps image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142821/google-maps-image), it is a similar question. But not so useful in my situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's not allowed.** See here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_screenshots

> Use of Google Maps imagery in printed materials **and offline media** is
>   subject to the Permission Guidelines published at:
>
> http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html

you can request permission, but I don't think it's easy to obtain, unless you are a paying  business customer.