# Save Google Map containing many markers as image

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-3, screenshot, google-maps-static-api

I recently asked about saving a google map as an image and this pointed me to using google static maps api, see:  [Save current Google Map as image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16235161/save-current-google-map-as-image).

However, I now have the problem that my map contains too many markers and the static map url I create becomes too long for browsers:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-33.942324329131765,25.552995870361304&size=950x780&zoom=14&maptype=roadmap&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.947032558,25.604918654000016&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.963374232,25.555530886000042&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.947930201,25.55912291499999&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.946769292,25.599957524000046&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.938220682,25.605319968000003&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.948348591,25.56376567799998&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.950216116,25.581719020000037&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.933032495,25.603185665999945&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.9482674,25.563609581000037&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.938193028,25.60551151599998&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.933300929,25.603159268000013&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.968700158,25.55439900600004&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.968596131,25.554452008999988&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.934990907,25.60488814300004&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.934927983,25.604891037000016&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.935197488,25.60385677599993&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.937367209,25.60520025200003&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.949374841,25.581271270000002&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.949337478,25.58134407800003&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.968608886,25.554294922000053&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.909966234,25.61213563499996&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.969171935,25.554816915999936&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.957948005,25.555829625&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.910026469,25.61217207200002&markers=size:mid|color:0xFF0000|label:C|-33.93997277,25.605487017999962...&sensor=false&key=...

I have tried the [HTML2CANVAS](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) script but it does not render the map correctly - it shows only the markers and not the map background.

Is there another way to render a complex google map with many markers as an image?

Comment: what is this for?  do you simply want a picture of the map saved programmically?

Comment: yes, save the map as an image