# Google Maps Static API net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: javascript, google-maps, xmlhttprequest, google-maps-static-api

I need to get a static image of a map with a large number of polygons on it .

Reference is generated from the array which can be more than two thousand coordinates.

```
link += "&path=weight:5|fillcolor:"+color+"|"+params[i].cords[0].lat+","+params[i].cords[0].lng+"|"+params[i].cords[1].lat+","+params[i].cords[1].lng+"|"+params[i].cords[2].lat+","+params[i].cords[2].lng+"|"+params[i].cords[3].lat+","+params[i].cords[3].lng;
```

After this, I am assuming this URL to the 'img' element:

```
img.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?format=jpg&zoom=2&size=400x400"+ generateParamsForLink(params) +"&key="mykey"
```

When a request is sent , I get an error - net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

my short [url](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?format=jpg&zoom=2&size=400x400&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.871,6.718|53.597,7.289|53.933,7.758|54.21,7.184&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|54.547,7.661|54.267,8.236|54.599,8.724|54.883,8.147&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|54.883,8.147|54.599,8.724|54.93,9.222|55.217,8.643&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.58,5.937|52.313,6.494|52.65,6.938|52.92,6.379&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.92,6.379|52.65,6.938|52.986,7.391|53.259,6.83&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.259,6.83|52.986,7.391|53.32,7.852|53.597,7.289&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.597,7.289|53.32,7.852|53.652,8.323|53.933,7.758&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.933,7.758|53.652,8.323|53.983,8.802|54.267,8.236&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|54.267,8.236|53.983,8.802|54.312,9.292|54.599,8.724&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|54.599,8.724|54.312,9.292|54.64,9.791|54.93,9.222&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|54.93,9.222|54.64,9.791|54.965,10.299|55.258,9.73&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.634,5.632|51.37,6.177|51.707,6.606|51.974,6.059&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.974,6.059|51.707,6.606|52.043,7.043|52.313,6.494&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.313,6.494|52.043,7.043|52.377,7.489|52.65,6.938&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.65,6.938|52.377,7.489|52.709,7.943|52.986,7.391&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.986,7.391|52.709,7.943|53.04,8.406|53.32,7.852&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.32,7.852|53.04,8.406|53.369,8.878|53.652,8.323&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.652,8.323|53.369,8.878|53.697,9.359|53.983,8.802&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.983,8.802|53.697,9.359|54.023,9.849|54.312,9.292&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|54.312,9.292|54.023,9.849|54.347,10.349|54.64,9.791&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|54.64,9.791|54.347,10.349|54.669,10.859|54.965,10.299&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.693,5.342|50.432,5.875|50.769,6.29|51.032,5.755&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.032,5.755|50.769,6.29|51.104,6.713|51.37,6.177&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.37,6.177|51.104,6.713|51.437,7.144|51.707,6.606&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.707,6.606|51.437,7.144|51.77,7.583|52.043,7.043&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.043,7.043|51.77,7.583|52.101,8.03|52.377,7.489&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.377,7.489|52.101,8.03|52.43,8.486|52.709,7.943&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.709,7.943|52.43,8.486|52.758,8.95|53.04,8.406&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.04,8.406|52.758,8.95|53.084,9.424|53.369,8.878&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.369,8.878|53.084,9.424|53.408,9.906|53.697,9.359&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.697,9.359|53.408,9.906|53.731,10.397|54.023,9.849&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|54.023,9.849|53.731,10.397|54.051,10.898|54.347,10.349&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|54.347,10.349|54.051,10.898|54.37,11.409|54.669,10.859&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|54.669,10.859|54.37,11.409|54.686,11.929|54.988,11.379&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.095,5.467|49.834,5.991|50.169,6.4|50.432,5.875&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.432,5.875|50.169,6.4|50.502,6.817|50.769,6.29&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.769,6.29|50.502,6.817|50.834,7.242|51.104,6.713&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.104,6.713|50.834,7.242|51.165,7.674|51.437,7.144&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.437,7.144|51.165,7.674|51.494,8.115|51.77,7.583&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.77,7.583|51.494,8.115|51.822,8.564|52.101,8.03&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.101,8.03|51.822,8.564|52.148,9.021|52.43,8.486&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.43,8.486|52.148,9.021|52.473,9.486|52.758,8.95&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.758,8.95|52.473,9.486|52.796,9.961|53.084,9.424&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.084,9.424|52.796,9.961|53.117,10.444|53.408,9.906&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.408,9.906|53.117,10.444|53.436,10.936|53.731,10.397&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.731,10.397|53.436,10.936|53.753,11.438|54.051,10.898&path=weight:5|fillcolor:D69B2B|54.051,10.898|53.753,11.438|54.068,11.949|54.37,11.409&path=weight:5|fillcolor:D69B2B|54.37,11.409|54.068,11.949|54.381,12.469|54.686,11.929&path=weight:5|fillcolor:D69B2B|54.686,11.929|54.381,12.469|54.692,13|55,12.459&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.499,5.589|49.239,6.103|49.571,6.506|49.834,5.991&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.834,5.991|49.571,6.506|49.903,6.918|50.169,6.4&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.169,6.4|49.903,6.918|50.233,7.336|50.502,6.817&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.502,6.817|50.233,7.336|50.562,7.763|50.834,7.242&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.834,7.242|50.562,7.763|50.89,8.197|51.165,7.674&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.165,7.674|50.89,8.197|51.216,8.638|51.494,8.115&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.494,8.115|51.216,8.638|51.541,9.088|51.822,8.564&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.822,8.564|51.541,9.088|51.864,9.547|52.148,9.021&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.148,9.021|51.864,9.547|52.185,10.013|52.473,9.486&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.473,9.486|52.185,10.013|52.505,10.489|52.796,9.961&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.796,9.961|52.505,10.489|52.823,10.973|53.117,10.444&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.117,10.444|52.823,10.973|53.139,11.466|53.436,10.936&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.436,10.936|53.139,11.466|53.452,11.968|53.753,11.438&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.753,11.438|53.452,11.968|53.764,12.479|54.068,11.949&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|54.068,11.949|53.764,12.479|54.074,13|54.381,12.469&path=weight:5|fillcolor:D69B2B|54.381,12.469|54.074,13|54.381,13.531|54.692,13&path=weight:5|fillcolor:D69B2B|54.692,13|54.381,13.531|54.686,14.071|55,13.541&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.239,6.103|48.976,6.61|49.306,7.015|49.571,6.506&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.571,6.506|49.306,7.015|49.634,7.428|49.903,6.918&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.903,6.918|49.634,7.428|49.962,7.848|50.233,7.336&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.233,7.336|49.962,7.848|50.288,8.276|50.562,7.763&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.562,7.763|50.288,8.276|50.612,8.711|50.89,8.197&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.89,8.197|50.612,8.711|50.936,9.154|51.216,8.638&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.216,8.638|50.936,9.154|51.257,9.605|51.541,9.088&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.541,9.088|51.257,9.605|51.577,10.064|51.864,9.547&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.864,9.547|51.577,10.064|51.895,10.532|52.185,10.013&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.185,10.013|51.895,10.532|52.212,11.008|52.505,10.489&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.505,10.489|52.212,11.008|52.526,11.493|52.823,10.973&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.823,10.973|52.526,11.493|52.839,11.986|53.139,11.466&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.139,11.466|52.839,11.986|53.15,12.488|53.452,11.968&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.452,11.968|53.15,12.488|53.458,13|53.764,12.479&path=weight:5|fillcolor:D69B2B|53.764,12.479|53.458,13|53.764,13.521|54.074,13&path=weight:5|fillcolor:D69B2B|54.074,13|53.764,13.521|54.068,14.051|54.381,13.531&path=weight:5|fillcolor:D69B2B|54.381,13.531|54.068,14.051|54.37,14.591|54.686,14.071&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.976,6.61|48.711,7.109|49.038,7.516|49.306,7.015&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.306,7.015|49.038,7.516|49.364,7.931|49.634,7.428&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.634,7.428|49.364,7.931|49.688,8.352|49.962,7.848&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.962,7.848|49.688,8.352|50.011,8.781|50.288,8.276&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.288,8.276|50.011,8.781|50.333,9.217|50.612,8.711&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.612,8.711|50.333,9.217|50.653,9.662|50.936,9.154&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.936,9.154|50.653,9.662|50.971,10.114|51.257,9.605&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.257,9.605|50.971,10.114|51.288,10.574|51.577,10.064&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.577,10.064|51.288,10.574|51.603,11.042|51.895,10.532&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.895,10.532|51.603,11.042|51.916,11.519|52.212,11.008&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.212,11.008|51.916,11.519|52.228,12.004|52.526,11.493&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.526,11.493|52.228,12.004|52.537,12.497|52.839,11.986&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.839,11.986|52.537,12.497|52.844,13|53.15,12.488&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.15,12.488|52.844,13|53.15,13.512|53.458,13&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.458,13|53.15,13.512|53.452,14.032|53.764,13.521&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.764,13.521|53.452,14.032|53.753,14.562|54.068,14.051&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.038,7.516|48.768,8.011|49.09,8.426|49.364,7.931&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.364,7.931|49.09,8.426|49.412,8.849|49.688,8.352&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.688,8.352|49.412,8.849|49.732,9.279|50.011,8.781&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.011,8.781|49.732,9.279|50.05,9.716|50.333,9.217&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.333,9.217|50.05,9.716|50.367,10.161|50.653,9.662&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.653,9.662|50.367,10.161|50.683,10.614|50.971,10.114&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.971,10.114|50.683,10.614|50.997,11.075|51.288,10.574&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.288,10.574|50.997,11.075|51.309,11.544|51.603,11.042&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.603,11.042|51.309,11.544|51.619,12.021|51.916,11.519&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.916,11.519|51.619,12.021|51.927,12.506|52.228,12.004&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.228,12.004|51.927,12.506|52.233,13|52.537,12.497&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.537,12.497|52.233,13|52.537,13.503|52.844,13&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.844,13|52.537,13.503|52.839,14.014|53.15,13.512&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.15,13.512|52.839,14.014|53.139,14.534|53.452,14.032&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|53.452,14.032|53.139,14.534|53.436,15.064|53.753,14.562&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|47.792,6.806|47.528,7.289|47.851,7.685|48.118,7.201&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.118,7.201|47.851,7.685|48.174,8.088|48.443,7.602&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.443,7.602|48.174,8.088|48.495,8.498|48.768,8.011&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.768,8.011|48.495,8.498|48.815,8.914|49.09,8.426&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.09,8.426|48.815,8.914|49.133,9.338|49.412,8.849&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.412,8.849|49.133,9.338|49.45,9.769|49.732,9.279&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.732,9.279|49.45,9.769|49.766,10.207|50.05,9.716&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.05,9.716|49.766,10.207|50.08,10.653|50.367,10.161&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.367,10.161|50.08,10.653|50.392,11.107|50.683,10.614&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.683,10.614|50.392,11.107|50.703,11.568|50.997,11.075&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.997,11.075|50.703,11.568|51.012,12.037|51.309,11.544&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.309,11.544|51.012,12.037|51.319,12.514|51.619,12.021&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.619,12.021|51.319,12.514|51.624,13|51.927,12.506&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.927,12.506|51.624,13|51.927,13.494|52.233,13&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.233,13|51.927,13.494|52.228,13.996|52.537,13.503&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.537,13.503|52.228,13.996|52.526,14.507|52.839,14.014&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.839,14.014|52.526,14.507|52.823,15.027|53.139,14.534&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|47.528,7.289|47.262,7.766|47.582,8.163|47.851,7.685&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|47.851,7.685|47.582,8.163|47.902,8.567|48.174,8.088&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.174,8.088|47.902,8.567|48.22,8.978|48.495,8.498&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.495,8.498|48.22,8.978|48.537,9.396|48.815,8.914&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.815,8.914|48.537,9.396|48.853,9.82|49.133,9.338&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.133,9.338|48.853,9.82|49.167,10.252|49.45,9.769&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.45,9.769|49.167,10.252|49.479,10.691|49.766,10.207&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.766,10.207|49.479,10.691|49.79,11.137|50.08,10.653&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.08,10.653|49.79,11.137|50.1,11.591|50.392,11.107&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.392,11.107|50.1,11.591|50.407,12.053|50.703,11.568&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.703,11.568|50.407,12.053|50.713,12.523|51.012,12.037&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.012,12.037|50.713,12.523|51.017,13|51.319,12.514&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.319,12.514|51.017,13|51.319,13.486|51.624,13&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.624,13|51.319,13.486|51.619,13.979|51.927,13.494&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.927,13.494|51.619,13.979|51.916,14.481|52.228,13.996&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.228,13.996|51.916,14.481|52.212,14.992|52.526,14.507&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|52.526,14.507|52.212,14.992|52.505,15.511|52.823,15.027&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|47.582,8.163|47.311,8.635|47.628,9.04|47.902,8.567&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|47.902,8.567|47.628,9.04|47.943,9.451|48.22,8.978&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.22,8.978|47.943,9.451|48.257,9.87|48.537,9.396&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.537,9.396|48.257,9.87|48.57,10.295|48.853,9.82&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.853,9.82|48.57,10.295|48.881,10.728|49.167,10.252&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.167,10.252|48.881,10.728|49.191,11.167|49.479,10.691&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.479,10.691|49.191,11.167|49.499,11.614|49.79,11.137&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.79,11.137|49.499,11.614|49.805,12.068|50.1,11.591&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.1,11.591|49.805,12.068|50.11,12.53|50.407,12.053&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.407,12.053|50.11,12.53|50.412,13|50.713,12.523&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.713,12.523|50.412,13|50.713,13.477|51.017,13&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.017,13|50.713,13.477|51.012,13.963|51.319,13.486&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.319,13.486|51.012,13.963|51.309,14.456|51.619,13.979&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.619,13.979|51.309,14.456|51.603,14.958|51.916,14.481&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.916,14.481|51.603,14.958|51.895,15.468|52.212,14.992&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|47.628,9.04|47.352,9.505|47.664,9.918|47.943,9.451&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|47.943,9.451|47.664,9.918|47.975,10.337|48.257,9.87&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.257,9.87|47.975,10.337|48.285,10.763|48.57,10.295&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.57,10.295|48.285,10.763|48.593,11.196|48.881,10.728&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.881,10.728|48.593,11.196|48.9,11.636|49.191,11.167&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.191,11.167|48.9,11.636|49.205,12.083|49.499,11.614&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.499,11.614|49.205,12.083|49.508,12.538|49.805,12.068&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.805,12.068|49.508,12.538|49.81,13|50.11,12.53&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.412,13|50.11,13.47|50.407,13.947|50.713,13.477&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.713,13.477|50.407,13.947|50.703,14.432|51.012,13.963&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.012,13.963|50.703,14.432|50.997,14.925|51.309,14.456&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|51.309,14.456|50.997,14.925|51.288,15.426|51.603,14.958&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|47.352,9.505|47.073,9.964|47.383,10.378|47.664,9.918&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|47.664,9.918|47.383,10.378|47.691,10.797|47.975,10.337&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|47.975,10.337|47.691,10.797|47.998,11.224|48.285,10.763&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.285,10.763|47.998,11.224|48.304,11.657|48.593,11.196&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.593,11.196|48.304,11.657|48.607,12.098|48.9,11.636&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.9,11.636|48.607,12.098|48.91,12.545|49.205,12.083&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.205,12.083|48.91,12.545|49.21,13|49.508,12.538&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.508,12.538|49.21,13|49.508,13.462|49.81,13&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.703,14.432|50.392,14.893|50.683,15.386|50.997,14.925&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|50.997,14.925|50.683,15.386|50.971,15.886|51.288,15.426&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|47.073,9.964|46.793,10.417|47.1,10.831|47.383,10.378&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|47.383,10.378|47.1,10.831|47.406,11.251|47.691,10.797&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|47.691,10.797|47.406,11.251|47.71,11.678|47.998,11.224&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|47.998,11.224|47.71,11.678|48.012,12.112|48.304,11.657&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.304,11.657|48.012,12.112|48.313,12.552|48.607,12.098&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.607,12.098|48.313,12.552|48.612,13|48.91,12.545&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.91,12.545|48.612,13|48.91,13.455|49.21,13&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|49.21,13|48.91,13.455|49.205,13.917|49.508,13.462&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|47.406,11.251|47.118,11.698|47.419,12.125|47.71,11.678&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|47.71,11.678|47.419,12.125|47.719,12.559|48.012,12.112&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.012,12.112|47.719,12.559|48.017,13|48.313,12.552&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.313,12.552|48.017,13|48.313,13.448|48.612,13&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.612,13|48.313,13.448|48.607,13.902|48.91,13.455&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|48.91,13.455|48.607,13.902|48.9,14.364|49.205,13.917&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|47.419,12.125|47.127,12.566|47.424,13|47.719,12.559&path=weight:5|fillcolor:C1303C|47.719,12.559|47.424,13|47.719,13.441|48.017,13&&key="myKey") =)

I will be glad to any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have over 16k characters in your URL.  I'm afraid this API won't work the way you want it to

Here is the link to the section of the API documentation where the limit is stated to be 2048 characters: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#url-size-restriction

You should also url encode like so `img.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?format=jpg&zoom=2&size=400x400"+ encodeURIComponent(generateParamsForLink(params)) +"&key="mykey"`

You also have an extra ampersand before the key in your generated version, I'm guessing that's because the last item in params in empty.

Hope this helps, sorry I don't have better news.  I'd suggest using an embedded google map, but disabling interaction.

If you really need the image, here is a post that has a solution, I have not tested it and cannot vouch for how well it works.  If it works for you, please let me know!

[Google Maps image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142821/google-maps-image)

Comment: Thank you, I apparently missed the information on size restrictions.

I used static maps to generate pdf file . Perhaps you know how I can do without them ?

Comment: @AntonGorshenin I just updated the answer, please do let me know if that works for you. I have run into a similar problem in the past generating a map to embed in a PDF for print that was not high enough resolution because of the size restrictions.  We ultimately decided to forgo the map at that time, but I wasn't able to find this solution back then.

Comment: I also could not find a solution for the construction of large data through the Static API . At the same time I also tried to use OSM + mapbox + leaflet_image. This solution allows to place a string of 4096 characters. But this is unfortunately not enough for my purposes ( 
Now I try to use highcharts maps.

Comment: Good luck @AntonGorshenin! If you find a solution perhaps post it as an answer, I don't know the SO protocol when the question changes like this, but I would love to see an answer to static mapping with large datasets.